# how to kill parallel program of R in Linux

Tags: linux, r, rparallel

I use R to do parallel computing. Every time, when I want to kill the parallel program, I always use `kill 2130 2131 6456`(PID). Is there a way to kill all the programs of R?[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "kill"? Brutally stop the work in progress or stop the initialization of clusters after the work is done? Also, which package do you use to perform parallel computing?

Comment: I want to stop it before it finishes. I use `foreach`. After I run the parallel program, I use `top` in the terminal to see the processes. I kill the process by `kill PID`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do

```
 killall R
```

or

```
 killall -9 R
```

So see the help pages for `pgrep` and related utilities.  Also useful is `htop` instead of `top` and just hitting `k` for *kill* in it.

There are a bazillion such helper programs -- google for 'useful command-line programs' and eg [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/107217/how-to-manage-processes-from-the-linux-terminal-10-commands-you-need-to-know/) comes up.